# Auto-shorten the URL in JS or Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In Twitter, if you post a link in tweet, for example, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699459/get-title-content-via-link-in-rails`

the URL automatically changes to a shorten one:
[image]

And the correspongding Html is:

```
  <span class="invisible">http://</span>
  <span class="js-display-url">stackoverflow.com/questions/8699</span>
  <span class="invisible">459/get-title-content-via-link-in-rails</span>
```

(the `http://` and `long part`is hidden)

So How can I achieve this? I believe it's something with JS? or How should I approach this with Rails?

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282100/ruby-on-rails-generating-bit-ly-style-uuids

Comment: Uhm....I'm not looking for that kind of link shortner, just want to hide some part of a URL

Comment: Perhaps this is more what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338870/how-to-implement-a-short-url-like-urls-in-twitter

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for or at least close to it.

```
aHref.innerHTML = aHref.match(/([\w\d\-_]*\.)+(\w*$|\w*\/[\w\d]*)/)[0];
```

In short; this ignores the protocol:// and takes every string ending in "." (for sub domains) until it reaches the last item (could be "com", could be "uk" as in "co.uk") denoted by either "$" (end of the string) or a "/" followed by an alphanumeric string. With the resulting string it replaces the innerHTML or displayed content value.

So for example: "http://test.couch.com/333/fire" would become "test.couch.com/333"

Edit: I should add that I've only accounted for

```
A-Za-z0-9 and -_
```

in the url up to the "/" and only

```
A-Za-z0-9
```

For the remainder.

Edit 2: Using in Rails controller

The same principle applies but without the innerHTML since it's a DOM element property

```
 url = url.match(/([\w\d\-_]*\.)+(\w*$|\w*\/[\w\d]*)/).first
```

The line above will do the same thing as the javascript or at least will create the same shortened url.

If you mean how to use with the a helper:

```
shortUrl= url.match(/([\w\d\-_]*\.)+(\w*$|\w*\/[\w\d]*)/).first
link_to  shortUrl, url
```

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for. And how can I use it in controller? I mean, in twitter, the Link is auto-shortened when posted out, but I have no idea in doing this

Comment: @cqcn1991 I've added an example f its use in a Rails controller, although it's almost identical to the original example.